# For as long "as" ... ? When is the last as not used? What are the rules?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

For instance:

> For as long as it takes...

but

> For as long we have a future...

I know how to use them because I heard them being used, but I don't know whether there is a rule or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know where you heard the second one, but it is incorrect.  *For as long as* (or just *as long as*) is the only correct choice from your examples:

> For as long as it takes...
>
> For as long as we have a future...

*[As long as](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/long)* (see def. 37) is an idiom which has the following three meanngs:

> **a.** provided that: *As long as you can come by six, I'll be here.*
> **b.** seeing that; since: *As long as you're going to the grocery anyway, buy me a pint of ice cream.*
> **c.** Also, **so long as**. during the time that; through the period that: *As long as we were neighbors, they never invited us inside their house.*

I'm assuming definition **c** for the two examples, but definition **a** also fits the second example.  If that is the definition intended, then the *for* should be removed:

> As long as we have a future...